# How to setup a REST API for Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, discord.js

Im new to REST API's and i have been trying to get one up and working for discord.js for quite some time and i just cant seem to figure out how to get this working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

current code gives the error `FetchError: invalid json response body at https://api.psychonautwiki.org/?=%7B%20%20substances%20%7B%20%20%20name%20%20%20%20effects%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20name%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%7D%7D reason: Unexpected token G in JSON at position 0`

here is the main code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const querystring = require('querystring');

    module.exports.execute = async(message, args) => {

        const query = querystring.stringify({ term: args.join(' ') });

        if (!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send('You need to supply a search term!');
        }

        const { list } = await fetch(`https://api.psychonautwiki.org/?={  substances {   name    effects {      name    }  }}`).then(response => response.json());
        if (!list) return message.reply('no');

        message.channel.send(list);
    }
```

API Setup:

```
    substances(limit:300) {
        name
        url
        summary
        featured
        addictionPotential
        crossTolerance
        dangerousInteraction {
            name
        }
        class {
            chemical
            psychoactive
        }
        tolerance {
            full
            half
            zero
        }
        effects {
            name
            url
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using `fecth` you need to specify a bit more

- remember that is a GraphQL, to query you need to use `POST` instead of `GET`
- you also need to make sure you're passing the content type
- and then you need to send the `query` parameter in the body, and because it's `fetch` you will need to convert to a string

so the full query will end be like:

```js
fetch('https://api.psychonautwiki.org', { 
  method: 'POST', 
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify({ 
    query: "{ substances { name effects { name } }}"
  })
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => console.log(json))
```

and will return:

```
{
  "data": {
    "substances": [
      {
        "name": "1,4-Butanediol",
        "effects": [
          {
            "name": "Empathy, affection and sociability enhancement"
          }, 
          ...
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

you can even run in your browser console:

[image]

---

**added**

here's a great resource on [how to query GraphQL API's](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/4-simple-ways-to-call-a-graphql-api-a6807bcdb355)

Comment: im not recieving all info back now. ```Promise { <pending> }
{
  data: {
    substances: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ]
  },
  extensions: {
    tracing: {
      version: 1,
      startTime: '2020-04-30T20:32:58.593Z',
      endTime: '2020-04-30T20:32:58.652Z',
      duration: 58990406,
      execution: [Object]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a parameter that you need to pass for paging ...

Comment: if you use `{ substances(offset:0, limit: 10, query: "1B-LSD") { name effects {name} } }` you will get 78 effects for example... just check the Schema and play with it.